# compiling gzweb with gazebo 7.3

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I tried compiling gzweb for the latest version of gazebo..

```
 Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012-2016 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
```

Node version `v4.2.6`

But I am unable to compile as it throws errors like

```
gzweb/tools/gzcoarse.cc:113:28: error: ‘const class gazebo::common::SubMesh’ has no member named ‘GetVertex’
     inVertex = _inSubMesh->GetVertex(i);
```

and this seems to be true as there doesn't seem to be any GetVertex in the Submesh? Does gzweb work with gazebo7 or should I downgrade?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13886/compiling-gzweb-with-gazebo-7.3/) by [lonewolf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2673/lonewolf/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. GzWeb currently doesn't support new versions of Node, so you'll need to downgrade to 0.10 first. According to [these](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) instructions, first remove your current node:

   ```
    sudo apt-get remove nodejs
   ```

   then install the 0.10 version:

   ```
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.10 | sudo -E bash -
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ```

   You can use similar instructions to go back to node 4 if you need to.
2. The default branch of GzWeb has been compatible with Gazebo 7 for a while, but the latest "release" version 1.2.0 was not. I just created a new branch `gzweb_1.3.0` from default, which should build against gazebo7. So you could just pull and use the new branch ;)

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lonewolf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2673/lonewolf/) on 2016-07-13**:
@chapulina Thanks a lot.. That worked great ..

**Comment by [nzlz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2816/nzlz/) on 2016-09-18**:
gzweb_1.3.0 branch worked.